# Path issue after URL REWRITE

Tags: php, nginx, path, url-rewriting

I have an issue after applying the URL REWRITING on my Debian/Nginx/PHP server.

[Image issue screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia8j8.png)

My images don't show up.

### My Structure

- Class
- css
- img
- ...
- **and my file.php here**

### Don't working way / Working way

**This is not working**

If my image is stored in **/img/subfolder/img.svg**

```
<img src="/img/subfolder/img.svg">
```

**This is working**

If my image is stored in **/img/img.svg**

```
<img src="/img/img.svg">
```

### My rewriting in Nginx

rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?app=$1&page=$2&param=$3;

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? What path I should use to access to my image ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone have the same issue, my solution may help.

I changed my rewriting rules from :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?app=$1&page=$2&param=$3;
}
```

To

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /app {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?app=$1&page=$2&param=$3;
}
```

The difference is that the rewriting rule is only apply when you requesting

```
mywebsite.com/app/...
```

So my new links are now like this :

```
mywebsite.com/app/myapp/mypage/param
```

Instead of :

```
mywebsite.com/myapp/mypage/param
```